# Pivoting Data in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a result set like below :

```
MinID       MaxID   ColumnName
----------  ------- -------------------
167         34458   AccountManager
174         174     ClientDeliveryDate
184         184     LocalContactEmail
192         34459   ProjectDeveloper
194         194     ServiceType
```

I want a result set like :

```
AccountManager ClientDeliveryDate LocalContactEmail ProjectDeveloper ServiceType
-------------- ------------------ ----------------- ---------------- -----------
167            174                184               192              194
34458          174                184               34459            194
```

Comment: Go to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select [AccountManager], [ClientDeliveryDate], [LocalContactEmail],[ProjectDeveloper] ,[ServiceType]
from
(
    SELECT ColumnName, TestType, score
    FROM 
    (
        SELECT ColumnName, MinID, MaxID  from table_name
    ) PivotData
    UNPIVOT
    (
        score for TestType IN (MinID, MaxID)
    ) as initialUnPivot
) as PivotSource
PIVOT 
(
MIN(score) FOR ColumnName IN ([AccountManager], [ClientDeliveryDate], [LocalContactEmail],[ProjectDeveloper] ,[ServiceType])
) AS PivotTable
order by [AccountManager] desc
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/196fe/1)**

Answer (score -1):

Try this query.

```
SELECT 
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'AccouontManager'  then `MaxID` end) as AccouontManager, 
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'ClientDeliveryDate'  then `MaxID` end) as ClientDeliveryDate,
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'LocalContactEmail'  then `MaxID` end) as LocalContactEmail,
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'ProjectDeveloper'  then `MaxID` end) as ProjectDeveloper,
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'ServiceType'  then `MaxID` end) as ServiceType
FROM `your_table` 
union all 
SELECT 
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'AccouontManager'  then `MinID` end) as AccouontManager, 
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'ClientDeliveryDate'  then `MinID` end) as ClientDeliveryDate,
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'LocalContactEmail'  then `MinID` end) as LocalContactEmail,
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'ProjectDeveloper'  then `MinID` end) as ProjectDeveloper,
max(case when `ColumnName` = 'ServiceType'  then `MinID` end) as ServiceType
FROM `your_table`
```

Comment: What if there are **10 columns.**
1. Will you write **10 union all**
2. What if columns values are changed. it is bound to **fail in 90 cases out of 100**

Comment: I don't know about pivot that's y i written like this.

Comment: I haven't run this, it should do the job but it's not scalable.